# Need help with an script executed in terminal

Tags: compiling, gnome-terminal, command-line

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this script?

```
`for i in {1..7};

do for j in {1..5};

 $a =$ix630;

 $y =$jx900;

 do 
mogrify 
-crop $ax$y+675+900 +repage /home/vas/Documents/Web_Design/Mold%20ISEF%202014/poster/Ready/body_final.png; 

done;

 done`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to perform some multiplications in the nested `for` loops and assign the values to `a` and `y`?

Check out the values generated here:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..7}; do
    for j in {1..5}; do
        a=$(( $i*630 ))
        y=$(( $j*900 ))
        echo "a: " $a "y: " $y
    done
done
```